# ¿Se pude introducir un discurso directo con una pregunta, sin el verbo de lengua luego de esta?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, puntuación, redacción

Esa es la pregunta global, pero son tres las preguntas específicas: ¿Es correcta una construcción como la primera? ¿O tendría que introducir obligatoriamente ese verbo de lengua (que incluí en el segundo caso) que el orador no usó en su conferencia? ¿Las comillas tienen que así o abarcar todo, desde el comienzo hasta el final de la cita?

> ¿Qué decían antes?: «Son los funcionarios», «El presidente no se
> entera», «El presidente es buena persona, pero los que lo rodean son
> corruptos y el presidente no se da cuenta».
>
> ¿Qué decían antes? [Decían:] «Son los funcionarios», «El presidente no
> se entera», «El presidente es buena persona, pero los que lo rodean
> son corruptos y el presidente no se da cuenta».

Gracias de antemano, amigos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que es una decisión de estilo, porque ambas son forma comprensibles de incluir lo dicho por otros
En relación a las tres cosas que específicamente consultas:

- ¿**Es correcta una construcción como la primera?** 

  Si, es entendible y válida
- ¿**Tendría que introducir un verbo de lengua como en el primer caso?** 

  Es posible, pero no indispensable. Puedes usar esa manera si consideras que aporta mayor claridad. Asimismo el uso del [corchete](https://www.rae.es/dpd/corchete) en este caso es adecuado, siendo que, como dice la RAE, `"se utiliza, por lo general, de forma parecida a los paréntesis que incorporan información complementaria o aclaratoria"`
- **¿Las comillas tienen que ir así, o abarcar todo, desde el comienzo hasta el final de la cita** 

  Parece ser una enumeración de distintas frases, por lo tanto correspondería poner a cada una entre comillas. De lo contrario —si bien son cosas efectivamente dichas a propósito de lo mismo— estarías introduciendo cierta confusión al ser expresiones éstas independientes, hechas en momentos distintos.